# Can UCMA and Lync Server SDK be used to implement this scenario?

Tags: lync, ucma

Is it possible to use UCMA and/or the Lync Server SDK to write a web application that can do the following:

1. Report the state of any in-progress calls for a specific user in the web page (active/on hold and duration)
2. Place an active call on hold/retrieve from on hold on behalf of a user
3. Transfer an active call to another user

In this situation, the user will have the Lync client and the web browser running on their local computer.  I'm looking for a way to not require custom software installed on their desktop and hopefully for something that supports both Windows and Mac operating systems.

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge this is possible with UCMA, but to control the calls you need to make them BackToBack (B2B) calls.

Re-route all incoming SIP Invites to an application endpoint, from there accept the call and set up a B2B call to the original recipient. A B2B call means that the two calling parties will connect directly to eachother but the SIP messages are relayed through your application endpoint, thus allowing the endpoint to see the call status, and manipulate it (redirect/forward/hold/terminate/etc).

Because only the SIP data is routed through your endpoint, and the actual call data streams are directly between the calling parties, this approach is very scalable.

By routing like this, your application endpoint can keep track of who is calling who, for how long, and what the current call status is (catch on-hold events, etc). Exposing this information through a website or webservice is trivial.

Since all of this can be done from an application endpoint (a server), and you display information on a website, there should be no problems with operating systems or different versions of lync clients.